# UI not updating on 'pageinit', probably timing issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-init

I have the following `.js` file for my project. This is running in a regular browser, using jquery 1.9.x and jquerymobile 1.3.1. The init function below appears to be running when the page loads and the UI is not updated. ***Though...*** I *can* copy the function into the console and run it, and the UI updates as it is supposed to, so this in *not* a case of incorrect file paths, or incorrect ids for the UI elements, but I suspect timing. I am also NOT using cordova or phone gap in this instance.

So, my question is, why is the UI not updating when the `$(document).bind('pageinit', ...)` function is called? If I put a breakpoint in the init method, it is getting called when the page loads. Any suggestions on using a different event or approach?

```
var simulator = simulator || {};

(function (feedback, $, undefined) { 'use-strict';
    feedback.init = function () {
        $.get('feedback-config.xml', function (data) {
            $('#feedback-to').val($(data).find('email').text());
            $('#feedback-subject').val($(data).find('emailSubject').text());
            $('#feedback-display').html($(data).find('message').text());
            $('#feedback-form').attr('action', $(data).find('serverurl').text()).ajaxForm({success: function () {
                alert("Thank you for your feedback!");
            }, error: function () {
                alert("We're having difficulties sending your feedback, sorry for the inconvenience.");
            }});
        });
    };
}(simulator.feedback = simulator.feedback || {}, jQuery));

$(document).bind('pageinit', function () { 'use strict';
    simulator.feedback.init;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: Didn't help. Maybe it's not a timing issue, but what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, simple mistake... In the 'pageinit' function I am calling `simulator.feedback.init;` instead of `simulator.feedback.init();` Not sure why JSLint didn't pick that up initially, but it pointed it out when I tried again later. Thanks.